# Why this variable auto edit?

Tags: c

Contest : I have a vector and i need to shift it by left (dir=1) or right(dir=-1) so far a very simple thing, only in the for loop I don't know why but many times the dir variable is changed for i don't know what reason.
Could someone please explain me why?
Precisely it is changed by itself when the function returns.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxN 6
void ruota(int v[maxN],int N,int P,int dir)
{
    //rotazione a destra
    switch(dir){
        case -1:
        {
            for(int i=P;i<N;i++)
            {
                int mod=i%P;
                //scambio
                int tmp=v[mod];
                v[mod]=v[i];
                v[i]=tmp;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1: //rotazione a sinistra
        {
            for(int i=N-P;i>=0;i--)
            { int mod=N-i%P;
                //scambio
                int tmp=v[mod];
                v[mod]=v[i];
                v[i]=tmp;
            }


        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int pos;
    int dir=0;
    int vet[maxN];
    printf("Acquisizione vettore \n");
    for(int i=0;i<maxN;i++)
    {scanf("%d",&vet[i]);}
    printf("Posizione: \n");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    printf("Direzione: \n");
    scanf("%d",&dir);
    for(;pos>0;pos--)
    {
        ruota(vet,maxN,1,dir);  //Why this function change dir variable?
    }
    //stampa
    for(int i=0;i<maxN;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",vet[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you supplying as input to your test execution?

Comment: usually vector: 1 2 3 4 5 6 , position: 3 , dir= 1  (cause i'm testing left shift , right work good)

Comment: And what did your debugger tell you was the *first* thing your program did that was unexpected?

Comment: Please [edit] and show an example of input along with the expected vs the actual output. All the interactino in Italian isn't helpful fon non itaalian speakers

Comment: Your code is doing `i%P` and `P` is always 1, so that will always evaluate to 0.

Comment: @Jabberwocky INPUT: in the vector 1 2 3 4 5 6 , position: 3 , dir : 1  
expected output : 4 5 6 1 2 3 
the problem is that the dir variable that stand for 'direction' change unexpectedly when the second call to 'ruota' happn , but it does not change in the function , it change in the return , but it shouldn't change , another thing that i notice if the vector is for example: 345678 the dir change to 3 , i notice that always change with v[0] and idk why

Comment: @cossser please [edit] the question and put all relevant information _there_.

Comment: @Kevin is right but i developed the function for so that I could move by P digits in the function, but according to the task I had to call the function several times depending on the position (pos variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 'rotate left' branch you have

```
        for(int i=N-P;i>=0;i--)
        { 
            int mod=N-i%P;
            //scambio
            int tmp=v[mod];
            v[mod]=v[i];
            v[i]=tmp;
        }
```

With `P == 1` as `ruota()` is called, `i%P` will always be 0 thus `mod == N`.
So when you assign `v[mod]=v[i]` you have a buffer overflow which in your case overwrites `dir`

Comment: That's right i was accessing the dir variabile trough v[6] wich didn't exist 
i editet int mod=N-i%P-1